# Установка языка Perl в Linux

Tags: linux, debian, perl

Не получается установить perl-5.34.1 через инструмент Perlbrew.
Использую официальный мануал [perlbrew.pl](https://perlbrew.pl/Installation.html)

Также пробовал через сайт metaspan [metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew)

Если кто устанавливал  через данную утилиту пожалуйста подскажите. Мне нужно установить Perl отдельно от системного в образовательных целях. И Perlbrew очень похож на инструмент в языке программирования Ruby -> (RVM), вот я и хочу разобраться в данном инструменте, который позволит переключаться на разные версии языка не повредив системе. Работаю в (Debian/Devuan).

Благодарю за ответ на мой вопрос.

Всем добра!

Comment: Если Вы пишите, что оно не получается, то надо уточнить, на каком шаге это происходит, какие ошибки возникают. А то может под капотом arm m1 или ещё что нибудь странное

Comment: perlbrew.pl - там скачивается скрипт, который запускается в bash. Где-то происходит ошибка. Попробуте сделать так: скачать скрипт в виде файла себе. Затем открыть его в редакторе, и вставить первой командой `set -x` - это режим отладки. Затем запустить - bash этот-скрипт.sh. То что он выведет - в студию.

Comment: У вас дистрибутив без менеджера пакетов? Почему устанавливаете так странно?

Comment: @TotalPusher, `bash -x ...` и никаких правок в скриптах.