# Perl5 perlbrew проблема с установкой

Tags: linux, perl, установка

Работаю по этому мануалу:
https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew

1. Installation - установка работает, создает каталог в домашней директории

   curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
2. Initialize - инициализация пишет: ~$ bash: perlbrew: команда не найдена

   perlbrew init

[image: init]

При написании source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc инициализация заработала

[image: Initialize]

3. See what is available - просмотр доступных версий видит.

   perlbrew available

[image: available]

4.Install some Perls - пишет пояснения в терминале.

perlbrew install 5.35.1

perlbrew install perl-5.35.1

[image: Возможная проблема]

See what were installed - установленные версии не видит!

perlbrew list

Возможное решение в этом. Может быть Perlvrew не работает с последней версией.

Пожалуйста кто работает с данной утилитой подскажите решение.

В теории данный способ должен быть удобным и работать в linux не затронув системный Perl.

Благодарю за ответ.

Всем добра!

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1412454/2739

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, нечетные версии - это версии для разработчиков, то есть промежуточные. Они выходят каждое 20 число месяца и могут включать экспериментальные функции, которые не войдут в последующие релизы. Другими словами, работайте только с четными версиями.

Так же, Вы сами показываете вывод `perlbrew available`, в котором устанавливаемой вам версии (5.35.1) нет. Подозреваю, что Perlbrew вообще нечётные версии не поддерживает, просто не зачем.

То, что предлагают поставить с форсом (-force), это просто установка без тестирования, чего так же крайне не рекомендуется делать, по крайней мере новичкам.